# Unable to add a variable fetched from an api to a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

the problem is that the field in the database where the data from the api request should be says "0 fields". i think it's because mongo inserts the object to the database before the api response is in the object's variable. so i think i need to let the database insert function wait until the api request is done.

does anyone know how i can get this thing done?

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

var mongodb = require('mongodb')
var mongoDbQueue = require('mongodb-queue')

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'
const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })

const app = express();


// View engine setup
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', __dirname);

// Static folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('main');
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
  var item = {
  name: req.body.name,
  age: req.body.age,
country: req.body.country,
  isValid:
 fetch(*/normaly working url inside here*/)  
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => isValid = data)
      .then(() => console.log(isValid))

}



client.connect(err => {
    const db = client.db('test')
    const queue = mongoDbQueue(db, 'my-queue')


  queue.add(item, (err, id) => {
 
  })

  })



});



app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started...'));
```

`.then(() => console.log(equivalent))` gives me the right value, so it hasn't to do with the api

Comment: So you basically need to add an entry to the DB after the /send fetch has completed, right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the asynchronous nature of the fetch API. The value inside isValid is not resolved until a later point in time. Also you are using the value incorrectly.

The below code waits for the response, sets the value, and updates the db within the correct scope.

```
app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
 fetch(*/normaly working url inside here*/)  
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(isValid => {
       var item = {
        name: req.body.name,
        age: req.body.age,
        country: req.body.country,
        isValid //same as isValid : isValid
      }
      client.connect(err => {
       if(!err) { // error check
         const db = client.db('test');
         const queue = mongoDbQueue(db, 'my-queue');
         queue.add(item, (err, id) => {})
       }
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve here,
but my guess is that you want to add a database entry when the fetch
promise has been settled at the /send route. In that case, you need to 
refactor your code like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

var mongodb = require('mongodb')
var mongoDbQueue = require('mongodb-queue')

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'
const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })

const app = express();

// View engine setup
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', __dirname);

// Static folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('main');
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    let name = req.body.name;
    let age = req.body.age;
    let country = req.body.country;
    fetch( /* normaly working url inside here */)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            let item = { name, age, country, isValid: true };
            // data is ready to be used or added to the database at this point:
            client.connect(err => {
                const db = client.db('test')
                const queue = mongoDbQueue(db, 'my-queue')
                queue.add(item, (err, id) => {
                })
            })

        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));

});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started...'));
```

Comment: Now the console returns Promise { <pending> }.

Comment: Updated. Now you have access to data, the result of the fetch, and you can add it to the database via the item object. In case the fetch results in an error, you will have to deal with that in the catch clause.